# form with 2 int inputs where one always has to be lower and one always has to higher

Tags: html, reactjs, forms

I think its's pretty clear in my code what I am trying to do. basically I'm trying to use the max and min parameter from the input to make it so that they can never cross each other. This doesn't work of course, I am using react and am using usestate to set the values whenever the form is submitted and pass these variables into my database fetch. I feel like using 2 states one for the temporary value of the input and one to pass the submitted value to the fetch is not a good way of solving this.

```
const [ LowestPrice, setLowestPrice ] = useState(0)
const [ HighestPrice, setHighestPrice ] = useState(500)

useEffect(() =>{
const getProps = async () => {
const { data, count, error } = await backbase.from('products_2')
      .select('*', { count: 'exact' })
      .gte('price', LowestPrice)
      .lt('price', HighestPrice)
      .range(indexOfFirstItem, indexOfLastItem - 1)
}}, [LowestPrice, HighestPrice])

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    setLowestPrice(document.getElementById("lowest_price")?.value)
    setHighestPrice(document.getElementById("highest_price")?.value)
  }

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="lowest_price">minimum price</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="lowest_price"
          defaultValue={LowestPrice}
          min={0}
          max={document.getElementById("highest_price")?.value}
        />
        <label htmlFor="highest_price">maximum price</label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="highest_price"
          defaultValue={HighestPrice}
          min={document.getElementById("lowest_price")?.value}
          max={500}
        />
        <button type="submit">apply filters</button>
      </form>
```

I left out unessential parts of the code to make it easier to read. It's the min and max in the form that are the most relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, don't use getElementById to listen to changes. React triggers a re-render on components when their value changes. In order to retain the value, we use useState. Secondly, you can use OnChange to compare between both values in state before deciding whether or not to discard the new value. Try something like this;

```
const [lowestPrice, setLowestPrice] = useState(0);
const [highestPrice, setHighestPrice] = useState(1);

return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <label htmlFor="lowest_price">minimum price</label>
    <input
      onChange={e => e.target.value <= highestPrice && setLowestPrice(e.target.value)} value={lowestPrice}
      type="number"
      id="lowest_price"
      defaultValue={lowestPrice}
      value={lowestPrice}
      min={0}
      max={highestPrice}
    />
    <label htmlFor="highest_price">maximum price</label>
    <input
      onChange={e => e.target.value > lowestPrice && setHighestPrice(e.target.value)}
      type="number"
      id="highest_price"
      defaultValue={highestPrice}
      value={highestPrice}
      min={lowestPrice}
      max={500}
    />
    <button type="submit">apply filters</button>
  </form>
)
```

Comment: Yes and this would of course be an easy solution. I have done this many times before but the thing is I don't want to rerender the page (and my API call) every  time the value changes. Only when you submit the form (thus when apply the changes).

Comment: Re-rendering doesn't happen on the page. The component does a re-render when it detects a change, but that just means the values are swapped out. The Form has e.preventDefault attached to the submission which means the page won't re-render either. Move your handleSubmit function out of the component too

Comment: Also, did you mean to do add lowestPrice and highestPrice as dependencies in your useEffect? This means that every time these values change the code inside the useEffect will trigger again. Are you sure yu don't want to handle this inside the onSubmit?

Comment: Do you mean my getProps/useEffect? I feel like I would then still need 2 useStates for each to to get teh values to applied one.

Comment: Yes handling the API call in onSubmit I feel like will be a really good solution. But then how would I handle my initial API fetch, this one still has to take into consideration Highest-/LowestPrice and I have to add these then as dependencies.

The form indeed had e.preventDefautl() attached to it but changing the state does trigger the useEffect which triggers and changes the API call thus the page does rerender or at least kinda, The fetch wich is the only part in the ui that changes does rerender.

Comment: you would put your first call in a useEffect with no dependencies; `useEffect() => { ... }, []);`

Comment: I know how I'm gonna solve this problem now, thanks for the help